# kafka confluent .NET 1.8.2 How to override max.poll.interval.ms in the consumer config?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

My application has to consume messages from a kafka topic at specific time or when triggered.
So when my consumer sits there without consuming messages, it gets removed from the consumer group.

```
Application maximum poll interval(300000ms) exceeded by 277ms (adjust max.poll.interval.ms for long-running message processing): leaving group
```

My understanding is that it is the consumer itself sending the request to the broker to be removed from the consumer group once the maximum poll interval is exceeded.  Is this config setting exposed in the Confluent Kafka .NET API version 1.8.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConsumerConfig` accepts a `MaxPollIntervalMs` attribute